# Fetching Date and year from Timestamp column (Athena)

Tags: sql, timestamp, amazon-athena

I'm working in Athena (SQL) and trying to extract the date, year and month from column called "createddate" which involves timestamp and its a varchar data type. I have tried bunch of queries but I am getting errors after errors. Can you please help me extracting the date, year, month, week from this createddate column?

The field "createddate" is found in the following format:

| id | createddate |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 11/29/2016 10:58:02 |
| 2 | 12/04/2016 07:07:58 |
| 3 | 10/22/2018 03:47:23 |
| 4 | 10/22/2018 08:20:25 |
| 5 | 10/22/2018 08:29:26 |
| 6 | 10/22/2018 08:42:28 |
| 7 | 10/22/2018 08:46:21 |
| 8 | 10/22/2018 10:18:57 |
| 12 | 10/22/2018 22:16:46 |
| 13 | 10/22/2018 22:24:33 |
| 14 | 10/23/2018 02:55:49 |
| 15 | 10/23/2018 07:49:39 |
| 16 | 10/23/2018 09:15:57 |
| 32 | 10/26/2018 06:19:13 |
| 33 | 10/26/2018 06:21:09 |
| 34 | 10/26/2018 06:24:59 |
| 48 | 10/30/2018 19:11:41 |
| 49 | 10/30/2018 20:10:10 |
| 64 | 11/01/2018 18:06:15 |
| 65 | 11/01/2018 18:08:00 |
| 66 | 11/01/2018 18:08:37 |
| 2 | 12/04/2016 07:07:58 |
| 99 | 11/09/2018 23:52:02 |
| 100 | 11/09/2018 23:57:13 |

Here are all my attempts:

```
select * from table where YEAR(from_iso8601_timestamp(createddate)) = 2022
and MONTH(from_iso8601_timestamp(createddate)) = 6 limit 10

select date_format(createddate,'%m/%d/%Y %H:%m:%s') from table limit 10

select date_format(createddate,'%m/%d/%Y H:m:s') from table limit 10

select date_format(createddate,'%m/%d/%Y %H:%i:%s') from table limit 10

select date_parse(createddate, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%i%p') from table limit 10

select date_parse(createddate, ' %m/%d/%Y') from table limit 10

select cast(date_parse(createddate,'%Y-%m-%d %h24:%i:%s') as date) from table limit 10

Select CAST(date_format(date_parse(cast(createddate as varchar(10)), '%m%d%Y'), '%m/%d/%Y') AS DATE) from table limit 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this one:

```
WITH cte AS (
       SELECT id,
              DATE_PARSE(createddate, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%i:%s') AS createddate
       FROM table
)
SELECT id,
       createddate, 
       YEAR(createddate),
       MONTH(createddate),
       WEEK(createddate)
FROM cte
```

You can find the documentation relative to the employed date functions [here](https://prestodb.io/docs/0.217/functions/datetime.html).

Comment: (i). When I ran your query, it gave me the following error:
"INVALID_FUNCTION_ARGUMENT: Cannot parse "11/29/2016 10:58:02": Value 29 for monthOfYear must be in the range [1,12]"

SELECT id,
              DATE_PARSE(createddate, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%i:%s') AS createddate
       FROM table

(ii). Then I changed the query to this: (i.e., changing the month location with day) but still I got an error:
SELECT id,
              DATE_PARSE(createddate, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%i:%s') AS createddate
       FROM table
INVALID_FUNCTION_ARGUMENT: Invalid format:

Comment: What about this `%c/%e/%Y %H:%i:%s`?

Comment: still getting that same error: 
INVALID_FUNCTION_ARGUMENT: Invalid format:

Comment: You may need to play with the formats: once you get the right format, you should be good to go. Check more formats at the half of the doc I've linked in my answer, or maybe add even more dates to the sample data of your post.

Comment: I tried bunch of them but couldn't get it. I have added more dates to my sample input data for your reference.

Comment: Is there a way to debug your code through an online tool like https://www.db-fiddle.com/?

Comment: I don't know how to do that. Is it possible to try the code with this sample input table in the post?

Comment: Unluckily neither https://www.db-fiddle.com/ nor https://dbfiddle.uk/ support PrestoDB. I may be unable to help you further as I may suggest tons of combinations and have a long chat here